# Firebase and Cordova - use Facebook's app credentials for login

Tags: cordova, firebase, facebook-login

I would like to be able to log my users to Firebase using Facebook login, but if they have the Facebook app installed, without needing to fill their infos again, just asking for the right permissions, as a lot of native apps does. Is it possible ?

[EDIT]

Using the official Facebook plugin and NGCordova implementation ( http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Facebook ) I was able to get the user logged using the credentials already on the phone - I guess Facebook's app ones. Of course it didn't log the user on my app using Firebase. I don't know if I'm on the right way though... And if I am, I don't get how to make a bridge.

[EDIT 2]

Apparently there is a function provided by Firebase to do this : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management-authwithoauthtokenprovider-credentials-options but for now I'm failing to get it working. Will come back and share the solution if I finally find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it working ! If anyone needs this in the future, here is how you do it :

- Create a Cordova (or Ionic) regular project
- Create a Facebook app. Yo ucan create after that a test app of that one, for easier testing.
- Add the plugin for Facebook : https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin and use the wanted installation (android in my case, it was a little complicated, pay attention to the keys hash step). If you do use Ionic, or another Angular based framework, you might want to use NGCordova : http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Facebook
- If you use a Facebook test app, be sure tu fill its field with Android keys hash if yo uwork on Android, and be sure to use its App ID and not the production one.
- On Firebase dont forget to fill ID and secret of your Facebook app.

Then, onclick on the Facebook login button, use something like this :

- With AngularFire :

  ```
  app.factory("firebaseRoot", [ function() {
      return "https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/";
  }])

  app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", "firebaseRoot", function($firebaseAuth, firebaseRoot) {
      var ref = new Firebase(firebaseRoot);
      return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }])
  ```

And in the controller :

```
    $scope.fblogin = function() {
        var options = {
            scope: "email,user_friends"
        };

        $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
            .then(function(success) {
                console.log(success.authResponse.accessToken);

                Auth.$authWithOAuthToken("facebook", success.authResponse.accessToken).then(function(authData) {
                    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Firebase Authentication failed:", error);
                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```

- or pure JS :

  ```
  function fblogin() {
  var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
  console.log(userData.authResponse.accessToken);

      var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com");
      ref.authWithOAuthToken("facebook", userData.authResponse.accessToken, function(error, authData) {
          if (error) {
              console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
              console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
          }
      });
  }

  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
      fbLoginSuccess,
      function (error) { console.log("" + error) }
  );
  }
  ```

Hope it helps !